# Black sreen after switching user

Tags: boot

Here is what is happening in details, in my Ubuntu 14.04 :

```
I log in as user "A"
Without terminating the session, I switch to user "B"
without terminating the session, i switch back to user "A" and there is a black screen in my monitor for a 3 seconds before start the session.
```

could you please someone help me with that... 
Thanks

Comment: Please, clarify your question. The screen keeps black or simply goes black for 3 second and then logins normally?

Comment: the monitor goes black like if the computer was off, I have to press "enter key" 2 or 3 times to start up the computer again in my session..

Comment: I don't know  what can be. However I upvoted the post, I'm sure that somebody can help you to fix it.

Comment: What graphics hardware and driver are you using???  Seems like a graphics issue.  (test by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][F1] and then again [Ctrl][Alt][F7] or [Ctrl][Alt][F8] to go back to User A or user B respectively.  If that "solves" the problem, it's definitely a hardware issue.  @Helio: just cc-ing you...

Comment: Thanks.. This is what I have, I tried but still the black screen after switching users.. *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:fe800000-febfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:ec90(size=8)